# Split Multi-dimensional Array Into Multiple Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [u_id] => 2
            [u_name] => Test USER
            [r_nb_today] => 2
            [r_nb_total] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [u_id] => 4
            [u_name] => Test USER
            [r_nb_today] => 0
            [r_nb_total] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [u_id] => 5
            [u_name] => Test USER
            [r_nb_today] => 0
            [r_nb_total] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [u_id] => 6
            [u_name] => Test USER
            [r_nb_today] => 0
            [r_nb_total] => 0
        )
)
```

The array is bigger than this, Now I want to keep it as is with the same order and split it into multiple arrays with a limit of 10 entries each (like LIMIT 10 in SQL).

How to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @devpro comment (write it here to have official answer):

You can use [array-chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) which chunks an array into arrays with size elements. The last chunk may contain less than size elements.

Use it in your case as:

```
$chuncks = array_chunk($array, $limit));
```